# Facebook caches og:image even after using cache buster parameter or changing image file name

Tags: facebook, caching, facebook-opengraph

I've shared a link on Facebook containing an `og:image` meta tag. Then I changed the content of `og:image` and posted the same link on Facebook again.
 **Problem:** Facebook is still showing the content of the `og:image` before it was changed.

There is no surprise that Facebook is caching the OpenGraph tags of the posts shared, but there should be a way to scrap the cache and re-fetch the content on-demand.

I have already tried a couple of approaches including:

- Renaming the image referred to in the `og:image` every time it's changed.
- Using a random value (cache buster parameter) at the end of the link that is posted.

Unfortunately, none of them have worked for me so far. Any suggestion is fully appreciated :)

Comment: What is the URL you are sharing?

Comment: You need to use Facebook’s [Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to rescrape your URL. Facebook caches your OG information the first time someone shares your page (or the first time you use the Debugger yourself) and they don’t check back, so changing your image name has no effect (although you should revise the image name each time you change for other apps that use OG information).

Comment: @RichDeBourke I am looking for an automatic way (API call or some changes in the URL I'm sharing) to purge the caching. Unfortunately in this case the Sharing Debugger tool won't work for me.

Comment: @WizKid I'm using something like this: `https://myWebsite.com/somePath?fbrefresh=1616054009205`

Comment: According to this [Facebook blog post,](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/612/) the answer is yes, there is a way to programmatically request Facebook to rescrape your URL (they scrape new information, rather than purging the old). It does involve making a POST call to Facebook, and I think it involves access tokens, but I have never tried it, so I don’t know the details.

Comment: Thank you @RichDeBourke that's really helpful! Will give it a try